# Select time difference in minutes for this months portion only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Cant figure out what im doing wrong:

I have a table that has a start time and end time column and im trying to figure out the sum of time in minutes for this months portion only.

Eg. 
Start date: 27-02-13
End Date: 03-03-13

Over all minutes= 5760
Minutes for March only: 4320

This is my query but its not working properly, i tried to add a where clause to look back the last two months for pervious time entrys. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
isnull((Sum(DATEDIFF(minute, 
CASE when datetime5 < dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,GetDate()), 0)
THEN dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,GetDate()), 0)
ELSE datetime5 END,
CASE when datetime6 > dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,GetDate())+1, 0)
THEN dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,GetDate())+1, 0)
ELSE datetime6 END))/60.0),0 )
as Minutes , 0 
FROM AllUserData 
WHERE tp_ListID in (select tp_ID from Lists where tp_Title = 'D1 Downtime')
and datetime5 >=dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,GetDate())-2, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d17fe/13).

```
with month_start_finish (month_start, month_finish) as 
(
  -- here you get the beginning of the current month and the next month
  -- needed for filters and calculations
  select 
    dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0),
    dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0)  
)
select start_date, finish_date,
  -- here you calculate your minutes
  datediff(minute, 
           case when start_date > month_start then start_date else month_start end,
           case when finish_date < month_finish then finish_date else month_finish end
          ) as minutes_in_this_month
from test, month_start_finish
where start_date < month_finish -- here you remove any periods that
and finish_date > month_start   -- are not related to the current month
```

Note how it works correctly even if the the period is longer than a month.

Answer (score 0):

Select all records that end after the beginning of this month.

Then, the portion of each record that is in this month can be obtained with something like this (pseudo-code):

```
end - max(start,start_of_this_month)
```

Take the start of the period or the start of this month, whichever is later.

This should help you simplify your query, I think.  Here is the basic idea (pseudo-code again, as I don't know the nuances of SQL Server date operations).

```
select sum(elapsed_time) from (
        select end - max(start,start_of_this_month) as elapsed_time
            from your table
            where end > start_of_this_month
    ) time_periods
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, im always happy to know theres an easier solution, can you give me an example using the info above?